# BIOS build number and Identification number?

Tags: wmi, bios

I want to get the BIOS Build number and Identification number. I am already using WMI class Win32_Bios dataclass but I it is not returing the value for Build number and Identification number on any of the windows OS.

can any one let me know how should I go to get the above fileds mentioned for bios?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the "build number", there is no specification that requires a BIOS vendor to provide a build number, so you will not always find one.

Regarding the "identification number" (by which I assume you mean the version number?), in my experience there is a field inside Win32_Bios called "SMBIOSBIOSVersion".  This would be the version number.